# Extract MAC address from string in javascript

Tags: regex, node.js, mac-address

I have a node.js app that needs to extract a MAC address from a string.

```
var str = "bridge=vmbr1,virtio=32:65:63:62:36:35";
```

The problem lies in the fact that the string is dynamic - it is not always in that format. It could also appear as...

```
var str = "bridge=vmbr1,virtio=32:65:63:62:36:35,firewall=1";
```

...among many other variations. For that reason, using something like split or substring won't work. I assume I might need to use some regex to extract just the `32:65:63:62:36:35` part from the string.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `str.match(/[A-F0-9]{2}(?::[A-F0-9]{2}){5}/g)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = "bridge=vmbr1,virtio=32:65:63:62:36:35,firewall=1";
str.match(/([0-9A-F]{2}:?){6}/g);

// output
// ["32:65:63:62:36:34"]
```

This will even work with multiple MACs in a single string.

```
str = "bridge=vmbr1,virtio=32:65:63:62:36:35,firewall=1,foo=32:65:63:62:36:39,bar=32:65:63:62:36:38";
str.match(/([0-9A-F]{2}:?){6}/g);

// output
// ["32:65:63:62:36:34","32:65:63:62:36:39","32:65:63:62:36:38"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/
```

Regex to match *standards group mac public listing*
[IEEE Std 802.1D and IEEE Std 802.1Q](https://standards.ieee.org/develop/regauth/grpmac/public.html) Reserved Addresses.

> The standard (IEEE 802) format for printing MAC-48 addresses in
>   human-friendly form is **six groups** of `two hexadecimal digits`, separated
>   by hyphens `-` or colons `:`

---

```js
string = "bridge=vmbr1,virtio=32:65:63:62:36:35,firewall=1";
result = string.match(/([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/);
document.write(result[0])
```